# Second Monitor not working via USB-C docker Ubuntu 20.04 after changing the docker

Tags: drivers, usb, lenovo, hdmi

I have 2 docking station (both usb-c) I used my second one yesterday and when I changed the docker today I can't get access to my second monitor. (the first one is connected directly to the laptop using the HDMI port). My outputs are the following:

When I run the `journalctl -b` command:

```
-- Logs begin at Tue 2022-10-18 08:31:59 EDT, end at Fri 2023-03-10 08:47:09 EST. --
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: Linux version 5.15.0-67-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-029) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #74~20.04.1-Ubun>
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-67-generic root=UUID=e0d80885-4d8c-436d-ac6b-fee0dc94268c ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x200: 'Protection Keys User registers'
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[9]:  832, xstate_sizes[9]:    8
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x207, context size is 840 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: signal: max sigframe size: 3376
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009efff] usable
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000009bfffff] usable
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000009c00000-0x0000000009da0fff] reserved
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000009da1000-0x0000000009efffff] usable
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000009f00000-0x0000000009f0efff] ACPI NVS
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000009f0f000-0x00000000c727dfff] usable
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c727e000-0x00000000cb47dfff] reserved
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cb47e000-0x00000000cd57dfff] ACPI NVS
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cd57e000-0x00000000cd5fdfff] ACPI data
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cd5fe000-0x00000000ce7fffff] usable
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ce800000-0x00000000cfffffff] reserved
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f8000000-0x00000000fbffffff] reserved
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fdc00000-0x00000000fdcfffff] reserved
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fe000000-0x00000000fe0fffff] reserved
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed80000-0x00000000fed80fff] reserved
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x00000003ae2fffff] usable
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000003ae300000-0x000000042fffffff] reserved
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: e820: update [mem 0x85d39018-0x85d46857] usable ==> usable
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: e820: update [mem 0x85d39018-0x85d46857] usable ==> usable
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: extended physical RAM map:
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009efff] usable
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000009bfffff] usable
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000009c00000-0x0000000009da0fff] reserved
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000009da1000-0x0000000009efffff] usable
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000009f00000-0x0000000009f0efff] ACPI NVS
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000009f0f000-0x0000000085d39017] usable
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000085d39018-0x0000000085d46857] usable
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000085d46858-0x00000000c727dfff] usable
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000c727e000-0x00000000cb47dfff] reserved
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000cb47e000-0x00000000cd57dfff] ACPI NVS
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000cd57e000-0x00000000cd5fdfff] ACPI data
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000cd5fe000-0x00000000ce7fffff] usable
Mar 04 16:54:46 fahim-IdeaPad-3-15ABA7 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000ce800000-0x00000000cfffffff] reserved
```

When I run the `xrandr` command:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.04*+
   1680x1050     60.04  
   1280x1024     60.04  
   1440x900      60.04  
   1280x800      60.04  
   1280x720      60.04  
   1024x768      60.04  
   800x600       60.04  
   640x480       60.04  
HDMI-A-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  74.97    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

When I run the `lshw -C display` command:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: c1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: iomemory:40-3f iomemory:40-3f irq:49 memory:460000000-46fffffff memory:470000000-4701fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:fd400000-fd47ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Lastly, when I run the `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:4853 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:550a Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b725 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 025: ID 1ea7:0066 SHARKOON Technologies GmbH [Mediatrack Edge Mini Keyboard]
Bus 001 Device 024: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**NOTE**: This used to work before in the same usb-c docker. Any advice would be appreciated thanks!